# Could not login to admin of my magento store

Tags: admin, magento-1.9

have changed my hosting few days back and realized my magento admin login stopped working. tried every possible solution provided by google but no luck. when i submit the credentials it return no errors just redirect me to the same admin login page with url -

http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/admin/index/index/key/c61d446704011292e96df5aa1f626cc7/

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @colin - setup is not on my local. it is properly hosted with a domain name.

Answer (score 1):

It may be your cache problem(CRTL+F5) to clear the browser cache and check it or find your admin user in database and reset the password. And try it

SELECT * FROM admin_user;

UPDATE admin_user SET password=CONCAT(MD5('qXpassword'), ':qX') WHERE username='admin';

Hope it will help you.

Comment: not working. tried both way.

Comment: The `admin/index/index` URL indicates that authentication was successful.  The problem is likely something session- or cookie-related.

Comment: Delete your session and cache files in var folder or rename them

Comment: I already tried this. deleted many times cache and  session but no luck. i am also wondering what else is left to make this working. i am running out of ideas.

Comment: Check whether your server space is enough or check in different browsers.

Comment: yes lot of space is left on server. and i have checked in chrome and firefox. same result from both browsers.

Comment: If you enter the user name and password it shows the error message or not check it

Comment: it doesn't show any error message.